# PulseAudio - Maximum number of channels

Tags: pulseaudio

Does PulseAudio has a limitation on number of surround channels streamed over HDMI? Does it support 9.2 LPCM for example?

I have an Intel NUC that's HDMI 2.0a capable. According to the specification, HDMI 2.0a can handle up to 32 channels of audio.

Unfortunately, I wasn't able to find an answer in PulseAudio documentation :(

Answer (score 0):

The PulseAudio documentation shown on [freedesktop.org](https://freedesktop.org/software/pulseaudio/doxygen/sample.html) says:

> PulseAudio supports up to **32 individual channels**. The order of the
> channels is up to the application, but they must be continuous.